# How to properly use the Ruby Git Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-git

I'm getting a "Incompatible Types" error in my code for cloning a remote repository (not private, open) but the problem is, when referring to the docs for the git gem, I *appear* to have the method setup correctly. Could somebody please review my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

# class ID declaration for the gitclone class
class Gitclone
  require 'fileutils'
  require 'git'
  require 'rubygems'
  # attribute reader so other classes/methods can read the instance vars in this class
  attr_reader :giturl, :destpa

  # init class method to set instance variables for giturl and destination path
  def initialize(giturl, destpa)
    @giturl = giturl
    @destpa = destpa
  end

  # class method to clone git repositories
  def clone
    puts 'Cloning the requested Git Repository now!'
    41.times do
      print '-'
    end
    puts $new_line
    sleep(2)
    # this bit here simply uses the Git gem to clone the repository URL stored in
    # the '@giturl' instance variable to the path stored in the '@destpa' instance variable
    return unless $softtype == 'Pixelated-Backup'

    Git.clone(github.com/Pixelated-Studios/Pixelated-Backup.git, path: /etc/pixelated/ruby/bin)


    # notify the user if the repository was cloned successfully
  end

  def gitcheck
    if Dir.exist?("/usr/local/pixelated/ruby/bin/#{$softtype}")
      puts "Successfully Cloned the Repo for #{softtype}!#{$new_line}"
    else
      puts "ERROR! Repo was not cloned! Did you give us the right link?#{$new_line}"
    end
    puts $new_line
  end
end
```

and here is the starter script that runs the class:

```
#!/bin/ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rubygems'
require 'git'
require 'ruby_figlet'
require('./vars/Globalvars')
require 'fileutils'
require 'io/console'

puts RubyFiglet::Figlet.new('Pixelated Installer').to_s

108.times { print '~' }
puts $new_line

sleep(2)

puts 'Starting the Pixelated Installer now!'

sleep(2)

# This part creates a password for a user then assigns it to the variable pwd
# I don't know if it works as it came from StackOverflow
### BEGIN PASSWORD GENERATOR ###
# def do_create_user(no,us,pw)
#  pwd = pw.crypt("$5$a1")
#  1.upto(no) do | x |
#         uname = us + x.to_s
#         result = system("useradd -m -p '#{ pwd }' #{ uname }")
#         if result
#                 puts "#{ uname } created!"
#             else
#                 puts "#{ uname } failed!"
#         end
#     end
# end
### END PASSWORD GENERATOR ###


#
# # this code was imported from a user on StackOverflow as a method to de-escalate user permissions to non-root
# # when running certain parts of the script
# #
# # This way a user can run the program as SUDO and we can make everything we don't need root for
# # run as a regular user instead of root
# #
# # I know this method works, I just don't know how to use it yet.
#
### BEING UNUSED CODE ###
# logname = User.find(session[:user_id]).name
# uname = logname.strip uid = Integer(id -u '#{uname}'.strip) gid = Integer(id -g '#{uname}'.strip)
#
# Drops privileges to that of the specified user
# def drop_priv user
#  Process.initgroups(user.username, user.gid)
#  Process::Sys.setegid(user.gid)
#  Process::Sys.setgid(user.gid)
#  Process::Sys.setuid(user.uid)
# end
#
# Execute the provided block in a child process as the specified user
# The parent blocks until the child finishes.
# def do_as_user user
#  unless pid = fork
#    drop_priv(user)
#    yield if block_given?
#    exit! 0 # prevent remainder of script from running in the child process
#  end
#  puts "Child running as PID #{pid} with reduced privs"
#  Process.wait(pid)
# end
#
# at_exit { puts 'Script finished.' }
#
# User = Struct.new(:username, :uid, :gid)
# user = User.new('nobody', 65534, 65534)
#
# do_as_user(user) do
#  sleep 1 # do something more useful here
#  exit! 2 # optionally provide an exit code
# end
#
# puts "Child exited with status #{$?.exitstatus}"
# puts 'Running stuff as root'
# sleep 1
#
# do_as_user(user) do
#  puts 'Doing stuff as a user'
#  sleep 1
# end
#
### END UNUSED CODE ###

puts 'What are you trying to install?'

31.times {print '-' }
puts $new_line

$softtype = gets.chomp

softtype = $softtype
puts $new_line

sleep(2)

puts "Ok! We will install #{softtype} for you!"
puts $new_line

sleep(2)

require('./classes/Gitclone')
require('./classes/Makedirectories')

Makedirectories.new

if $softtype == 'Pixelated-Backup'
  giturl = 'https://github.com/Pixelated-Studios/Pixelated-Backup.git'
  destpa = '/usr/pixelated/ruby/bin'
  Gitclone.new(giturl, destpa)
  Gitclone.clone
  #  Gitclone.gitcheck
# commented out for future use
# elsif
else
  puts 'ERROR! Git clone failed!'
end

sleep(1)
```

(PLEASE NOTE: I'm still very new to Ruby. So, please let me know about any noob errors I've made and don't judge me too harshly. Also, the sleeps are just for my own sake. They will be removed long before this is a finished project)

EDIT: I removed the quotes around the arguments, this helped somewhat but the PATH argument is still showing the error

EDIT2: Here is the full source, if anyone needs it: https://github.com/Pixelated-Studios/Pixelated-Ruby-Installer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).